# Post-nuclear war book where a boy ends up going into suspended animation until the Earth renews itself

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic, suspended-animation

I'm trying to find the title of a book I read as a kid, probably somewhere in late elementary days. I read this one around the same time as *The White Mountains* series by John Christopher, ~30 years ago, which I would also recommend to today's YA generation. Pretty creative stuff.

It's about a boy whose father has a secret underground garden because it's some sort of post-nuclear age where all the official food comes out of something like vending machines. The boy's father disappears and he goes on a search for him, and through a mysterious series of events ends up finding the last people on Earth strapping themselves into an airplane or spaceship to go into suspended animation until the Earth renews itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably Frank Bonham's [*The Missing Person's League*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590053876), first published in 1976 as per [What novel was set in a dystopian future and featured a boy searching for his missing father?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/what-novel-was-set-in-a-dystopian-future-and-featured-a-boy-searching-for-his-mi)

> The oddly-titled "The Missing Persons League" is a clever piece of science-fiction from author Frank Bonham. In his dystopian future, the world has nearly exhausted all its resources. Trees and grass no longer grow well, oxygen is in short supply, and the average American diet is full of government-produced imitations of real food. But Brian Foster, whose mother and sister disappeared a year before, has figured out a secret way to get around the shortages and live a better life than most, while maintaining a search for his lost family members.

The review I quoted doesn't mention it, but Brian and his father share a garden, built from smuggled dirt, and the ending does involve suspended animation.