# Dystopian kids’ novel in a society where growing your own food is illegal

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, dystopia

I read this book as a 4th grader around 1981-82. It was about a boy who lived in a society where growing your own food was illegal. At school he had to eat hard little pink cookies that cut up his mouth. But he and his dad had a secret garden, so they always had fresh vegetables. The veggies were powerful resistance, as the state-provided food contained drugs to keep the people docile.

I remember one crisis point in the novel was when the boy’s house was searched and they found tomato seeds in the drain.

Comment: Might be The Missing Persons League and thus dupe of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237799/story-where-real-food-is-illegal-but-there-is-an-underground-org-to-rebuild)?

Comment: Accepted at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/what-novel-was-set-in-a-dystopian-future-and-featured-a-boy-searching-for-his-mi?noredirect=1&lq=1